# How to address a French aristocrat by last name?

Tags: forms-of-address

For example, the full name of a French mathematician is Guillaume François Antoine, Marquis de l'Hôpital. Should I call him Monsieur de l'Hôpital, Monsieur l'Hôpital, or Monsieur Antoine?

Comment: I get the impression that de l'Hôpital was only an example, and you're actually dealing with the name of another person (potentially still alive today)... Is that right?

Also, what context will you be using this in? Are you addressing him (talking/writing TO him) or talking/writing ABOUT him?

Comment: I would be very interested in finding out which French _aristocrat_ would be both alive today _and_ willing to use his or her aristocratic title(s). It's not something that has been appreciated much in France since the revolution (both things: for aristocrats to be alive or use their titles.)

Comment: You'll have to use whatever rule goes in the French protocol, even if you talk to the nobility in English. Using last or first names is something not correct in French (although some people do it) so you have to use the name that goes with the title, when talking about the person "Monsieur le Marquis de l'Hôpital", and no name when addressing him, plain: "Monsieur le Marquis".

Comment: @oerkelens. We do have them. Just one example: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duc_d%27Albufera. Plenty of others.

Comment: @Laure I would recommend you write an answer to this question so the OP can accept it

Comment: @AlicjaZ. To be honest I think the question should have been asked on [fr.se](http://french.stackexchange.com), I did not ask for closure here but others might do. And if OP asks the question on [fr.se](http://french.stackexchange.com) there might be other better answers to choose from.

Comment: @Laure Fair enough.

Comment: When in France, follow French usage. But in the US he would usually be addressed as "Bill". Or possibly "Frank".

Comment: @StoneyB actually I'm just writing about him, and it felt strange to begin a name with "le" or "de"

Comment: @StoneyB Good point. And in Britain he'd probably be called "hey froggy!"

Comment: @AlexSu That makes sense. But on the other hand, would you write about da Vinci or Vinci?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think he will mind how you address him - he's been pushing up the daisies for some time now.

In general I would not worry too much about French aristocrats, or the need to address them.

In the late 18th century, the French had gotten so upset with their aristocrats, they organized a little [revolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Revolution), effectively doing away with the *concept* of aristocracy. Even the king was addressed as *citoyen* Capet before they separated him from his head.

Chances are that if you meet any Frenchmen who happens to have an aristocratic title today, they will (also) go by a "normal" last name, and you would be expected to use that name.

When you refer to the said mathematician, he's usually known simply as L'Hôpital.

Comment: I agree with you that L'Hôpital won't mind but the living counts dukes and other princes will probably mind if the likes of you and me address them! Found this for you: http://www.lefigaro.fr/lefigaromagazine/2009/05/02/01006-20090502ARTFIG00557--un-prince-francais-.php. Article written in 2008 (don't trust the date at the top of the page), far away from 1789. Maybe [this](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noblesse_d%27Empire) will be of some interest to you. But we're out of the site's scope, see you on fr.se if you like.